# Implementing a programming language without the specification

Tags: reverse-engineering

What if, instead of looking at the C++ specification, you analyze the behavior (by inspecting the source code and testing with sample inputs) of existing C++ compilers and use your knowledge of C++ to create a new compiler? Is it a good way to implement programming languages? What are the possible disadvantages of this approach?

Comment: This has the scent of an XY problem.  Is there a problem behind this question that you're really trying to ask?

Answer (score 3):

This happens all the time in the industry--it's reverse engineering. The compiler in this case is a black box (you have no idea how it does what it does), but you have some knowledge of its inputs and outputs. You can then create a new program that performs the same operations on inputs to get identical outputs.

In general, it's not a great way to do something if you have specifications, but there are cases where you need to find the internal workings of a system you have no control over, and this is a perfectly valid practice. You may, for instance, miss important implementation details and corner cases that don't always appear in the code, but are very clearly spelled out in the specification documents.

Answer (score 1):

To me, your questions sounds very similarly to "what if instead of using blueprints, we design a bridge by observing other bridges combined with our own experience of driving and walking over a bunch of bridges in the past?"

... I wouldn't step a foot on a bridge built with that methodology.

Specifications are there for a reason. People spend a lot of time and energy to generate those 100+ to 1000+ page documents so that every feature and every functionality is nailed down and ideally no ambiguity is left when it comes to deciding how a certain feature should work.

In essence, those specifications are the blueprints for a programming language. Without them the language would be as good as that hypothetical bridge that I just talked about.

Comment: No. I am going to carefully examine every implementation in hand to determine exactly how a feature should work.

Comment: @LinuxDistance for a programming language, are you sure you know how **everything** *should* work just by examining the output?

Comment: @LinuxDistance: You can do that. A good spec document is a blueprint. A source code for a compiler is also a blueprint. Both tell you exactly how a language is (should) be implemented. However, a) if looking at source code, how do you know the author of that particular compiler didn't make a mistake (look at stack overflow for all kinds of deep theoretical questions about c++, most compilers still have bugs); b) how do you know you won't make a mistake while reading compiler, some code can be quite hard to read and c) even if you can read and understand ALL source code for an entire...

Comment: ... I can promise you, that will take you way more time and energy than simply reading those 1000+ pages of spec.  You are still reading words, but instead of English, you are electing to read compiler instructions (aka source code). So besides the fact that there's many files and a lot of text, you are also not getting any thoughts, ideas and justification why language authors made certain language design decisions.

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can reverse engineer a compiler. An example off the top of my head, microsoft reverse-engineered the original JavaScript (maybe then livescript) compiler.

Why is this generally bad? Well consider what happened with JS, Microsoft almost exactly duplicated JavaScript, down to the bugs. This meant that every implementation quirk that really wasn't meant to be there was now part of their version. In fact, later on during the standardization process, MS forced some of these bugs into the standard*!
In your example, you'd find it almost impossible to reverse engineer C++/C, implementation defined behavior/undefined behavior is rampant! You'd have no way to separate standard, undefined, and incorrect behavior. This would lead to a substandard and overly complicated implementation on your part.

TLDR: Possible, yes. Advisable, no.

*And have subsequently poured money into typescript trying to undo some of those mistakes